# How to fix "TypeError: Every item in the descriptions list must be an AccessDescription"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am a novice python user trying to get a website's data to be parsed via Beautiful Soup. Whenever I run a get request, however, I get this certain error.

I downloaded the html file and used it to write the processing, but I can't get the online updating working. I was going according to this youtube guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng2o98k983k

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source=requests.get('https://rd2l.gg/seasons/bLikBZrRH/divisions/HJSzO_xoM/teams').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(r.text)
```

```
runfile('C:/Users/Akono/Documents/RD2L Season 18/RD2L DB/scrape and csv.py', wdir='C:/Users/Akono/Documents/RD2L Season 18/RD2L DB')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-225-654df9a749a6>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Akono/Documents/RD2L Season 18/RD2L DB/scrape and csv.py', wdir='C:/Users/Akono/Documents/RD2L Season 18/RD2L DB')

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Akono/Documents/RD2L Season 18/RD2L DB/scrape and csv.py", line 27, in <module>
    source=requests.get('https://rd2l.gg/seasons/bLikBZrRH/divisions/HJSzO_xoM/teams').text

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 355, in connect
    cert = self.sock.getpeercert()

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 363, in getpeercert
    'subjectAltName': get_subj_alt_name(x509)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 213, in get_subj_alt_name
    ext = cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(

  File "C:\Users\Akono\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cryptography\utils.py", line 170, in inner
    result = func(instance)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\x509.py", line 127, in extensions
    self._backend, self._x509

  File "C:\Users\Akono\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\decode_asn1.py", line 252, in parse
    value = handler(backend, ext_data)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\decode_asn1.py", line 400, in _decode_authority_information_access
    return x509.AuthorityInformationAccess(access_descriptions)

  File "C:\Users\Akono\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 286, in __init__
    def __repr__(self):

TypeError: Every item in the descriptions list must be an AccessDescription
```

Comment: What is print(r.text)? 
Sounds like you added portion of code, which is not enough to understand your problem. Elaborate more.

Comment: It's just supposed to print out the raw html of the page. I just want to check if I get anything out of the request. I don't see how that line of code might affect this issue, since the interpreter is already spewing out an error message due to the ```source=requests.get('https://rd2l.gg/seasons/bLikBZrRH/divisions/HJSzO_xoM/teams').text``` line of code.

Comment: I have a big example here (I have posted portion of code below),
https://github.com/dattatembare/file_downloader/blob/master/src/download/bony.py

Comment: When you use `soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')` something like this you have to install that python module.. I'm sure you have installed bs4. Try installing `lxml`

Comment: Yes, I have lxml installed. It works with downloaded pages. It just doesn't work with getting the source from a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this?

```
res1= requests.get(url)    
f_html = utils.format_html(res1.text)

def format_html(self, html_str):
        """
        format html page source, BeautifulSoup makes sure formatted output source is valid for parsing
        :param html_str: html page source string
        :return: formatted html
        """
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'html5lib')
        f_html = soup.prettify()
        logging.debug(f'Formatted html::: {f_html}')
        return f_html
```

Comment: No dice my dude, I literally copied this example and replaced the url variable with the url in question and it still gives the same error message. I did add all the imports and I did place the function definition above the code. It still says TypeError: Every item in the descriptions list must be an AccessDescription

Comment: I tried your code and that perfectly worked for me.I just replaces `print(r.text)` with `print(soup)`

Comment: `source=requests.get('https://rd2l.gg/seasons/bLikBZrRH/divisions/HJSzO_xoM/teams').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup)
`
This is what I changed the code to. Tried to run it. This is the error traceback:
[link](https://pastebin.com/yqBuee98)

Seems like some kind of issue with getting the page itself. Thanks for your efforts btw, I couldn't find any answer to this question anywhere else.

Comment: to elaborate more, i'm trying to replace 
`with open('teams.html', encoding="utf8") as teams_file:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(teams_file,'lxml')`
so that the soup is opened not from a file, but from this url https://rd2l.gg/seasons/bLikBZrRH/divisions/HJSzO_xoM/teams

Comment: Looks like its something specific to your work environment.
` File "C:\Users\Akono\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\decode_asn1.py", line 400, in _decode_authority_information_access
    return x509.AuthorityInformationAccess(access_descriptions)`

Just to make sure whether it work environment or workspace, create new workspace and just create one .py file(with above 4 lines of code) and run it